# How to fix broken line of table when querying information from database

Tags: php

am trying to get data from the database using php i have about four fields in my database, using the code below my table  gets broken when querying from database into the table..
this is mycode[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD4aA.png)

```
public function departments_view($dept_id){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM materials_tbl WHERE dept_id = $dept_id");
    $query->execute();
    if($query->rowCount()>0){


            ?>
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <?php 
                while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  
            ?>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Material Code</th>
                                    <th>Topic</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Path</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["material_code"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["topic"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["description"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["path"];?></td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
            <?php
             }    
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php

    }else {
        echo 'Nothing here.';
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my table gets broken"?

Comment: click on "enter image description here" to view the broken table, my data are sensitive so i decided to erase them. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,
Actually what mistake you've made is you've put table, tbody and table header inside the loop, that's why your table was breaking.

```html
public function departments_view($dept_id){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM materials_tbl WHERE dept_id = $dept_id");
    $query->execute();
    if($query->rowCount()>0){


            ?>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                       <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Material Code</th>
                                    <th>Topic</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Path</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                         <tbody>
            <?php 
                while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  
            ?>
       
                            
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["material_code"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["topic"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["description"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $row["path"];?></td>
                                </tr>

                            
            <?php
             }    
            ?>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
            </div>
            <?php

    }else {
        echo 'Nothing here.';
    }
}
```